# Fields that are not translated in the Mailchimp signup form

Tags: wordpress, transactions, mailchimp

I installed the Mailchimp plugin on my WP site. From the Mailchimp control Panel I translated all fields of the signup form from English to Italian but the label of the field 'Email Address' is not translated.
Furthermore, I've been able to translate the success message after subcription (as well as the message which indicates an existing email address) only from the mailchimp.php but, to the next update, the changes will be overwritten.
How can I change the email address label and messages just described correctly and safely?
Can you help me, please?